# How to add JSON data to a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, addeventlistener

Currently I'm fetching data that I need to add to a HTML table once I receive it.

I've tried a few things, but I'm not able to add the data dynamically once the page load.

I want to add it using Javascript or jQuery

Here is the HTML Structure :

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span>Email</span></th>
            <th><span>Last Name</span></th>
            <th><span>First Name</span></th>
            <th><span>Role</span></th>
            <th><span>Cell Phone User</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td scope="row" data-label="Email"></td>
                 <td data-label="Last Name"></td>
                 <td data-label="First Name"></td>
                 <td data-label="Role"></td>
                 <td data-label="Cell Phone User"></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is a sample of how the data looks once its fetched:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "janedoe@example.com",
    "familyName": "Doe",
    "givenName": "Jane",
    "role": "admin",
    "smsUser": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "johndoe@example.com",
    "familyName": "Doe",
    "givenName": "John",
    "role": "standard",
    "smsUser": false
  }]
```

Here is what I've tried so far :

this is my event listener to load the data once the page loads:

```
window.path = "http://localhost:3000/users";

// getUsers function plus any additional functions go here ...
const getUsers = options => {
  let url = new URL(window.path);
  if (options) {
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(options)
  }
  return Promise.resolve(fetch(url))
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

 /* SELECT DOM ELEMENTS*/ 
let table = document.querySelector('tbody');

let promise = getUsers({page=2, role:'admin'})

.then(data => {

var html = '<table>';
for( var j in data[0] ) {
    html += '<th>' + j + '</th>';
 }
     html += '</tr>';

     for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      html += '<tr>';
      for( var j in data[i] ) {
        html += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>';
      }
     }
     html += '</table>';
     table.appendChild(html)

    return table;
  })
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error fetching from /users', err);
    return null
  })

})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use jQuery it's verry simple, you can find documentation and examples at this link [https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html)

Comment: Why is your `html` variable string starting with `'<table>'` if you are using `querySelector` to get the `<tbody>` element tag?  If `table` is a reference to `<tbody>` then `table.append` should be given a string like `<tr><td>...</td></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the line

```
let promise = getUsers({page=2, role:'admin'})
```

should be

```
let promise = getUsers({page:2, role:'admin'})
```

Secondly, `appendChild` doesn't take a string, it takes a DOM element.  For this case, use innerHTML instead.

Thirdly, you are using querySelect to find the `'<tbody>'` element so start your construction of inner html tags at the `'<tr>'` not `'<table>'`

```js
const getUsers = async options => ([
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "janedoe@example.com",
    familyName: "Doe",
    givenName: "Jane",
    role: "admin",
    smsUser: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: "johndoe@example.com",
    familyName: "Doe",
    givenName: "John",
    role: "standard",
    smsUser: false
  }
]);
  
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('tbody');
  const users = await getUsers({ page:2, role:'admin' });
  const userToTableRow = user => [
  { attrs: 'scope="row" data-label="Email"', propName: 'email'},
  { attrs: 'data-label="Last Name"', propName: 'familyName'},
  { attrs: 'data-label="First Name"', propName: 'givenName'},
  { attrs: 'data-label="Role Name"', propName: 'role'},
  { attrs: 'data-label="Cell Phone User"', propName: 'smsUser'},
  ].map(mapper => (
    `<td ${mapper.attrs}>${user[mapper.propName]}</td>`
  )).join('');
  
  const html = users.map(user =>
    `<tr>${userToTableRow(user)}</tr>`
  ).join('');
  table.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><span>Email</span></th>
        <th><span>Last Name</span></th>
        <th><span>First Name</span></th>
        <th><span>Role</span></th>
        <th><span>Cell Phone User</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody> 
  </table>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I like the async/await in the first implementation above.  `async` is just a short hand way to force a function to wrap the return in a Promise. `await` is just a new language way to resolve a promise inline without having to use `.then((res) => {...})`. `await` can only be used in an `async` function.

Addressing questions in the comments.  I submit this alternative solution that:

- Does not use `async` and `await`
- mocks `fetch` instead of `getusers`
- Uses document.createElement() and appendChild instead of just setting the `innerHTML` content.

```js
const getUsersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/users';

function mockFetch(url) {
  const stubbedResponse = JSON.stringify([
    {
      id: 1,
      email: "janedoe@example.com",
      familyName: "Doe",
      givenName: "Jane",
      role: "admin",
      smsUser: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      email: "johndoe@example.com",
      familyName: "Doe",
      givenName: "John",
      role: "standard",
      smsUser: false
    }
  ]);

  return Promise.resolve({
    json() {
      return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(stubbedResponse));
    }
  });
}

const getUsers = options => {
  let url = new URL(getUsersUrl);
  if (options) {
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(options)
  }
  return mockFetch(url);
}

const userToTableRow = user => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  [
    {
      attrs: {
        scope: 'row',
        'data-label': 'Email'
      },
      propName: 'email'
    },
    {
      attrs: { 'data-label': 'Last Name' },
      propName: 'familyName'
    },
    {
      attrs: { 'data-label': 'First Name' },
      propName: 'givenName'
    },
    {
      attrs: { 'data-label': 'Role Name' },
      propName: 'role'
    },
    {
      attrs: { 'data-label': 'Cell Phone User' },
      propName: 'smsUser'
    },
  ].map(mapper => {
    const td = document.createElement('td');
    for (const [attrName, attrValue] of Object.entries(mapper.attrs)) {
      td.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue);
    }
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user[mapper.propName]));
    return td;
  }).forEach(td => { tr.appendChild(td); });
  return tr;
}
  
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('tbody');
  getUsers({ page:2, role:'admin' })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => {
      users
        .map(user => userToTableRow(user))
        .forEach(tr => { table.appendChild(tr); });
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><span>Email</span></th>
        <th><span>Last Name</span></th>
        <th><span>First Name</span></th>
        <th><span>Role</span></th>
        <th><span>Cell Phone User</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody> 
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Doug, can you explain the change to the getUsers function? currently the function is suppose to fetch data from a local endpoint then return a json. Also I don't understand the change of the promise variable.

Comment: also are you given the function a default param?

Comment: Your question just says what to expect from the `http://localhost:3000/users` endpoint.  Instead of trying to implement that server endpoint, I just mocked the signature... a function that returns a Promise that resolves to an array of users.

Comment: If by default param, you mean I am ignoring the value of the options parameter, then yes.  I'm just stubbing out the return value.

Comment: as for the promise variable.  You declared it, but never used it.  Instead of `async` and `await` keywords for shorthand, I could have done `let promise = getUsers({page:2, role:'admin'});` followed by `promise.then(users => {...})`

Comment: @bruce I edited my response to hopefully address your questions.

Comment: you did answer the questions. I should have been a little clearer. The both of your explanation makes sense. The alternative one was easier for me to get the gist. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it's very simple to do that.

Take this snippet as an example which leverages [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) library.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: {
          url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
          dataSrc: "data"
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "first_name" },
            { "data": "last_name" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name </th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

It also provides various configuration and integrations that I'm sure you'll find useful.